# Devops Azure not enough permission for hooks (for collaborator)

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops

I have a private repository. I added my friend as collaborator. Then I also made Devops Azure and added/installed Azure pipeline on GitHub.

Now, when my friend logs in on his Devops account, he wants to make a pipeline for the project I added him as a collaborator via GitHub. Good thing is he can see the repository from drop down list. When he chooses that and clicks `review and run`, Here is what the error states:

> Unable to configure a service on the selected GitHub repository. This
>   is likely caused by not having the necessary permission to manage
>   hooks for the selected repository

Any idea how I can fix it? or how I give him the enough permission for that?

Comment: Not get your response, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I reproduced your problem.

[image]

The cause of this problem is because your repository is private. If it is a personal repository, only the repository owner can create hooks. You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/200262/vsts-cicd-from-github-not-working.html) with similar issue.

If you **use the classic editor** to create a pipeline, you only need to be authorized with a GitHub personal access token.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is a personal repository, only the repository owner can create hooks. If it is an organization repository, you need at least "Admin permissions" which can "Change a repository's settings" with "Adding, removing, and editing webhooks and service hooks permission included. Refer to this link for details: https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/#changing-repository-settings